# Component in Angular material dialog es5 vs es6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to load a component inside a dialog, I did it in "old" style with $scope and dependency injection and it's working.

```
    angular
  .module("MyApp", ["ngMaterial"])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $rootElement) {
    $scope.inputText = "Hello from the Input"

    $scope.openDialog = function() {
      $mdDialog.show({
        template: '<test text="inputText"></test>',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        parent: $rootElement,
        scope: $scope,
        preserveScope: true,
      });
    };
  })
  .component('test', {
    template: '<span>{{ $ctrl.text || "Default Text" }}</span>',
    bindings: {
      text: '<'
    }
  });
```

["old" style codepen](http://codepen.io/kossel/pen/YGNOwo?editors=1011)

However I rewrite it to ES6 style, then the binding I'm trying to pass `text` is not longer available. any idea what am I missing?

```
class AppCtrl{ 
  constructor($mdDialog) {
    this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    this.inputText = "Hello from the Input";
    this.openDialog = this.openDialog.bind(this);
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.show({
      template: '<test text="this.inputText"></test>',
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      preserveScope: true,
    });
  }; 
}

angular
  .module("MyApp", ["ngMaterial"])
  .component('test', {
    template: '<span>{{ $ctrl.text || "Default Text" }}</span>',
    bindings: {
      text: '<'
    }
  })
  .controller('AppCtrl',AppCtrl);
```

[ES6 style codepen](http://codepen.io/kossel/pen/ORWoXN?editors=1011)

Comment: You still need to pass the scope with `scope: $scope,`. Use `$ctrl.inputText` in template instead.

Comment: tried that, but not working :/  injected $scope, and passed it to show(), still not workin as expected

Comment: Well, 'old style' doesn't work for me either, just dark overlay and no modal. Any way, it is as simple as that, `$rootElement` and `$scope` should persist in ES6.

Comment: I jsut test the old style, it works :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with the implementation, seems that ES6 is working  now

http://codepen.io/luchaca/pen/qaRroz?editors=1011

```
 class AppCtrl{ 
  constructor($mdDialog) {
    this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    this.inputText = "Hello from the Input";
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.show({
      template: '<test text="vm.inputText"></test>',
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      controller:()=>this,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
  }; 
};

angular
  .module("MyApp", ["ngMaterial"])
  .component('test', {
    template: '<span>{{ $ctrl.text  }}</span>',
    bindings: {
      text: '<'
    }
  })
  .controller('AppCtrl',AppCtrl)
```

Comment: Controller shouldn't be an arrow because it is a constructor.

Comment: Sorry my bad I was changing the implementation

Comment: This is another way using a mockCtrl http://codepen.io/luchaca/pen/qaRroz?editors=1010

Comment: Here is the codepen with the first code, using the arrow function http://codepen.io/luchaca/pen/ZpLqBd?editors=1011